# Drupal Webforms - recipient

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm using Webforms Drupal module to create a simple contact form . I added all the fields, but I don't know where to define the recipient. For example, I want to send the form results to example@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `index.php?q=node/%nid/webform/emails` where `%nid` is the node-id of you webform form.